# How to find AMI ID for specific region and instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am looking for a solution how to find AMI ID for specific region and instance type because I am receiving en error in terraform
I am doing it in eu-west-1 region.

```
Error: Error launching source instance: UnsupportedOperation: AMI 'ami-5c78753a' with an instance-store root device is not supported for the instance type 't2.micro'. 
status code: 400, request id: 419c4079-bfba-477b-8f13-020bf93af4e9
```

Comment: I usually log in to the AWS web console and then look for the AMI IDs.

Comment: @MarkoE It is not a point of view. Where do you see AMI ID in AWS web console? Are you talking about existing instance?

Comment: I don't understand the remark about PoV. Here's the way it's described by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html. There you can find AMI ID and if it can be used with an instance-store root device.

Comment: I don't see the AMI ID. Could you explain how to find this?

Comment: Log in to the AWS console. Find EC2. Look for `AMIs` on the left hand side. Search for the AMI ID that's causing issues. In the Details section for AMIs (bellow the AMI list), check if the AMI you want to use can in fact be used with instance-store root device.

Comment: Can you show me a  AMI-ID for eu-west-1 and an instance type 't2.micro'?

Comment: You have to find the AMI first, check if it can be used the way you want to use it. I don't see how the AMI ID is related to the instance type. But if you tell me which OS it is, I could do it. The question is, would I want to do it, as right now I'm not sure if you're just trying to prove me wrong or you're genuinely asking.

Answer (score 0):

The AMI with ID `ami-5c78753a` does exist in `eu-west-1` region. It's a Ubuntu image (an old one): `ubuntu/images/ubuntu-precise-12.04-i386-server-20170502`. If you look for the information in the `Details` section, you will notice two things:

1. it's a 32-bit OS
2. its virtualization type is `paravirtual`

I won't get into too much details about `paravirtual` (more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html)), but the part that also interests you is that it's a 32-bit OS. This combination is rather unfortunate, because not all instance types can be used with a `paravirtual` virtualization type and additionally it's a 32-bit OS (most of newer instance types are 64-bit). That means that the instance types that can be used in your situation are limited to these four:

- `m1.small`
- `m1.medium`
- `c3.large`
- `c1.medium`

You could change your Terraform code to use one of these, or you could use another version of Ubuntu, i.e. another AMI.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a map of the AMI's in each region that you could be deploying to and use the AMI id based on the region your deploying to.